# $(...).dialog is not a function error in mvc5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

window  based on drop down selection. In that i am getting this error **$(...).dialog is not a function** I tried many ways by using jquery plugins. Still issue is not cleared

**My view code**

```
@model ThreeTierArchitectureMVC.Models.VisitorsFormModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "SaveVisitorsForm";
 }
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

 @using(Html.BeginForm())
 { 

 <form>
<fieldset>

 <div class="col-sm-3">
 <div class="form-group">
 <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
 @Html.Label("Purpose of Visit", new { @class = "control-label", styles = "font-family: Arial;" })
 @Html.DropDownList("POVisitID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control required" })

 <div id="dialog-modal" title="Trial Form" style="display:none"></div>
  </div>
  </div>


  <script src="~/javascript/jquery-1.10.4-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/javascript/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="~/javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="~/javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
  <script src="~/javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    $('#POVisitID').change(function () {
        if ($('#POVisitID option:selected').text == "Trial") {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
        }
      })
   })

   $(function () {
    debugger;
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width: 500,
        maxHeight: 800,
        draggable: true,
        dialogClass: 'main-dialog-class',
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        },
        open: function () {
            var closeBtn = $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
            closeBtn.append('<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>');
        },
        close: function () {
            var closeBtn = $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
            closeBtn.html('');
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

The error is mention in the below image

[image: $ is not define error]
[image: Error]

I tried my level best to explain my issue. Any one help me to resolve this issue. Itried many ways still issue i snot cleared.

Thanks.

Comment: why so many jQuery and JQuery-ui library loaded on page?

Comment: How many copies of `jquery` and `jquery-ui` do you think your need (ONLY 1 of each)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes but i donno which plugins have to give exactly i am week in declare plugins . please tell what mistake i did stephen .

Comment: @vijayP i donno which plugins have to give exactly so only

Comment: keep only 3 library script tag: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`, `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="~/javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` in the same order. Remove all other and see.

Comment: @vijayP ok i have a try and let you know

Comment: @vijayP https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WLcg.jpg see this image i am getting error

Comment: i guess the path is not correct for bootstrap library. please cross verify that

Comment: @vijayP https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwDPB.jpg still error coming

Comment: Do you have any `<script>` tags in your Layout before `</body>`?

Comment: @dashtinejad what you are asking tell me clearly please? you asking in layout page

Comment: @snehasusan It seems that you have some `script` tag, especially jQuery one in your `_Layout.cshtml` between `@RenderBody()` and `</body>`.

Comment: @dashtinejad ok i have have check and let you know

Comment: @dashtinejad https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7eBo.jpg this is my layout page

Comment: @snehasusan Remove the two lines which contains `@Scripts.Render`.

Comment: @dashtinejad ok i have a check and let you know

Comment: @dashtinejad now no error but code is not working. That pop-up window code is not working

Comment: are you getting the correct **POVisitID** value from controller @snehasusan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct answer is

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    $("#POVisitID").change(function () {
        if ($("#POVisitID option:selected").text() == "Trial") {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
        }

    })
})

 $(function () {
    debugger;
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width: 500,
        maxHeight: 800,
        draggable: true,
        dialogClass: 'main-dialog-class',
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
          effect: "explode",
           duration: 1000
       },
        open: function () {
            var closeBtn = $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
            closeBtn.append('<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>');
        },
        close: function () {
            var closeBtn = $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
            closeBtn.html('');
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: why are you loading all the scripts more than once?